# Shiny Ui Layout

Tags: r, shiny

I want to position my output by coordinates. I have a segmentation image and I need to show the number of customers by each segment on its own segment.

Here is an image which contains the result I want:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuEcg.png)

I found a package called `shinyjgui`. With that package I can drag objects where ever I want but every time I run the app I need to do it again. 
I need a package that i can easily put objects where ever I want. With a code like `x=100, y=00`.

Thank you,

edit: 
I have this segmentation image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWLSo.png)

I want to put numbers on it.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: I had to do the same for my team, as they wanted to save/load profiles. You need to write the coordinates into a file and then upon shiny refresh,load that said file and check if that position was saved previously and then apply the changes

Comment: Actually I couldnt try anything because I couldnt find anything that meet my need. I used this code for dragging. `jqui_draggable(textOutput("OneTimer"))`

Comment: also absolute panel has coordinate values also, have a look https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/absolutePanel.html